# ggplot2 question - How to graph on a log scale for values < 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard

I've been playing with a shiny application to visualize data from the International Monetary Fund database.

One of the tabs in the application consists in plotting two indicators against one another using `geom_point()`.

I thought that plotting the data on a log scale might be helpful for visualization purposes, as the data distribution is often skewed.

On the one hand, no issues are encountered for values that are strictly positive.
On the other hand, since some indicators are measured in percent change, which can be negative, ggplot simply excludes the values from the graph (which makes sense given the fact that the log of a negative value is undefined).

Might sound like a weird question but here it is:

Is there a method by which you can show negative values, while still plotting the axes on a log scale?

Please take a look at the code below:

```
output$interact1 <- renderPlot({

x <- ggplot(filter(testplot, Year == input$y), 
            aes_string(x = input$indicator, y = input$indicator2))    

x + geom_jitter(aes_string( col = "Continent", size = "Population")) +

  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,50,100,200,1000)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_smooth(aes_string(input$indicator, input$indicator2), 
              method = "loess", col = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", show.legend = F) + 
  ylab(gsub("_"," ",input$indicator2)) + 
  xlab(gsub("_", " ", input$indicator)) +
  labs(caption = paste(gsub("_"," ",input$indicator2), 
                       "vs.", 
                       gsub("_", " ", input$indicator)))})
```

The screenshot below may also be helpful in understanding what it is that I am trying to do here:

[image: GDP per capita vs GDP % Change]

***Edit:***

To answer a question asked below, the attached bar graph shows the distribution of GDP % Change in the year 2018 (I know the labels might be a little hard to read).[image: Bar plot of GDP % Change in 2018]

Comment: A common approach to plotting zeros in a log transformed universe is to add a tiny amount to 0. That way, the log is defined.

Comment: What is the smallest negative value in your data set? What does the distribution of the GDP percentage changes look like (bimodal, negatively skewed, etc)? Depending on the above, one solution might be to add an amount to all values and then use log-axis. You could also use a cubic root transformation, but its suitability might also depend on the actual data values.

Comment: Hey Roman, thanks for the reply. That would indeed work for values near 0. Any ideas on how to solve the problem for values that are way below 0, let's say, -5% for instance?

Comment: @Constantinos, I've added a bar plot in my post, hope this helps. For year 2018 the difference is not that big, but for some other years the max can be +60% while the lowest value is somewhere around -8%

Comment: Since a change of -5% means essentially the same same thing as a change of 5%, just in the opposite direction, it seems like you would want to document that visually. So you might do something like `sign(vec) * log(abs(vec))`, although then you can't use the log scale directly.

Comment: If your data are %-change, I would instead plot the corresponding ratios on a log-scale. If you don't want labels like "0.9" (i.e. -10%) you can use a custom labeller function instead. The scale will then also have appropriate spacing, like for example +100% being at the same distance from 0 as -50%.